# Flux.onErrorContinue argument type

Tags: java, flux, project-reactor

does anybody know the reason why `Flux.onErrorContinue` arguments as the following type:

```java
public final Flux<T> onErrorContinue(BiConsumer<Throwable, Object> errorConsumer) {
...
}
```

instead of

```java
public final Flux<T> onErrorContinue(BiConsumer<Throwable, T> errorConsumer) {
...
}
```

?

Answer (score 2):

Ok I think I just understood:

```java
Flux<Integer> f1 = Flux.fromStream(Stream.of(1));

Flux<String> f2 = f1.map(i ->{
    throw new RuntimeException("bang");
});

f2.onErrorContinue((t, o) -> {
    System.out.println("o = " + o.getClass());
}).subscribe(System.out::println);
```

outputs:

```sh
o = class java.lang.Integer
```

From the flux of strings you can't know that the element that caused the problem was an integer, so the only option is to consider it as an object...